# The run button in CLion is invisible

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

I don't know how else to describe it.

It is there, it exists (as I can click on it to run my project) but its invisible.

I googled it, but all of the posts are about it being "greyed out"
[image: screenshot_of_clion]

I tried to re-run CLion, but the problem still persists or it randomly changes to a different icon pack.

Edit: Here is my plugins list
[image]

[image]

Comment: *"...or it randomly changes to a different icon pack"* Sounds like it is caused by one of the custom plugins. Disable icon/theming-related plugins (one by one) and restart the IDE. Do it until you find which one causes it. You seem to have at least one plugin for icons and one that affects progress bar.

Comment: True, I have the nyan cat progress bar thing

Comment: So... did disabling that plugin resolved the issue for you? If not -- do as I said and disable other plugins (other possible suspects: Extra ToolWindow Colorful Icons (low chance), Rainbow Brackets (not sure, but I know that it was causing certain issues in the past)). No idea about the rest of plugins (if they can have affect on your issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give up, uninstall the icon theme and cry about it, I did too ❤️